# Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters when installing Elastic Heartbeat

Tags: elasticsearch

I've installed Elastic Heartbeat (version 6.0.0 (amd64), libbeat 6.0.0) on Ubuntu (version Ubuntu 17.04) and connecting to an instance of Elasticsearch (version 5.6.4) on another server. Heartbeat starts up okay, but then throws an error when it attempts to send data to Elasticsearch.

In the logs I see:

```
2017-11-27T20:57:13Z DBG  PublishEvents: 5 events have been  published to elasticsearch in 7.248554ms.
2017-11-27T20:57:13Z WARN Can not index event (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]"}}
```

That error, for easier viewing says:

```
 2017 - 11 - 27 T20: 57: 13 Z WARN Can not index event(status = 400): {
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters: 
    [properties: {
      duration = {
        properties = {
          us = {
            type = long
          }
        }
      },
      scheme = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      },
      ip = {
        type = ip
      },
      host = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      },
      name = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      },
      id = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      },
      type = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      },
      status = {
        ignore_above = 1024,
        type = keyword
      }
    }]",
    "caused_by": {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  "
  }
```

The steps I took to install the package are:

```
> wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
OK
> sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
> echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install heartbeat-elastic 
> /usr/share/heartbeat/bin/heartbeat --version
heartbeat version 6.0.0 (amd64), libbeat 6.0.0

> vi /etc/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml
heartbeat.monitors:
- hosts:
  - 0.0.0.0:9190
  schedule: '@every 60s'
  type: tcp
- hosts:
  - 0.0.0.0:3030
  schedule: '@every 60s'
  type: tcp    
- hosts:
  - ****************:3306
  schedule: '@every 60s'
  type: tcp
logging.files:
  keepfiles: 7
  name: heartbeat.log
  path: /var/log/heartbeat
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
logging.to_syslog: false
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts:
  - http://****************:9200
  password: ****************
  username: elastic

> /usr/share/heartbeat/bin/heartbeat setup --template -c /etc/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/heartbeat -path.config /etc/heartbeat -path.data /var/lib/heartbeat -path.logs /var/log/heartbeat
Loaded index template

> /usr/share/heartbeat/bin/heartbeat setup --dashboards -c /etc/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/heartbeat -path.config /etc/heartbeat -path.data /var/lib/heartbeat -path.logs /var/log/heartbeat        
Loaded dashboards

> sudo service heartbeat-elastic restart
> sudo service heartbeat-elastic status
heartbeat-elastic.service - heartbeat
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/heartbeat-elastic.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-11-27 21:26:23 UTC; 1min 11s ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/index.html
 Main PID: 25014 (heartbeat)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 4.7M
      CPU: 49ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/heartbeat-elastic.service
           └─25014 /usr/share/heartbeat/bin/heartbeat -c /etc/heartbeat/heartbeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/heartbeat -path.config /etc/heartbeat -path.data /var/lib/heartbeat -path.logs /var/log/heartbeat

systemd[1]: Started heartbeat.
> tail /var/log/heartbeat/heartbeat.log -n100
    "scheme": "tcp",
    "id": "tcp-plain@0.0.0.0:9190"
  },
  "type": "monitor",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "*************",
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "name": "*************"
  }
}
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Job 'tcp-plain@0.0.0.0:9190' returned at 2017-11-27 21:33:25.82402829 +0000 UTC (cont=0).
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Next wakeup time: 2017-11-27 21:34:25.820400426 +0000 UTC
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2017-11-27T21:33:25.822Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "heartbeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.0.0"
  },
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "*************",
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "name": "*************"
  },
  "tcp": {
    "rtt": {
      "connect": {
        "us": 1719
      }
    },
    "port": 3030
  },
  "monitor": {
    "duration": {
      "us": 2203
    },
    "status": "up",
    "scheme": "tcp",
    "id": "tcp-plain@0.0.0.0:3030",
    "name": "tcp",
    "type": "tcp",
    "ip": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  "type": "monitor"
}
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2017-11-27T21:33:25.820Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "heartbeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.0.0"
  },
  "tcp": {
    "port": 3306,
    "rtt": {
      "connect": {
        "us": 2465
      }
    }
  },
  "monitor": {
    "ip": "*************",
    "duration": {
      "us": 3155
    },
    "status": "up",
    "scheme": "tcp",
    "id": "tcp-plain@*************:3306",
    "type": "tcp",
    "name": "tcp"
  },
  "type": "monitor",
  "beat": {
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "name": "*************",
    "hostname": "*************"
  }
}
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Job 'tcp-plain@0.0.0.0:3030' returned at 2017-11-27 21:33:25.828833688 +0000 UTC (cont=0).
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Next wakeup time: 2017-11-27 21:34:25.820400426 +0000 UTC
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Job 'tcp-plain@*************:3306' returned at 2017-11-27 21:33:25.828912205 +0000 UTC (cont=0).
2017-11-27T21:33:25Z DBG  Next wakeup time: 2017-11-27 21:34:25.820400426 +0000 UTC
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  ES Ping(url=http://gmri-metrics.upswell.io:9200)
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  Ping status code: 200
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z INFO Connected to Elasticsearch version 5.6.4
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  HEAD http://gmri-metrics.upswell.io:9200/_template/heartbeat-6.0.0  <nil>
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z INFO Template already exists and will not be overwritten.
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  PublishEvents: 3 events have been  published to elasticsearch in 13.392505ms.
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z WARN Can not index event (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]"}}
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z WARN Can not index event (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]"}}
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z WARN Can not index event (status=400): {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [monitor] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {duration={properties={us={type=long}}}, scheme={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, ip={type=ip}, host={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, name={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, id={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, type={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}, status={ignore_above=1024, type=keyword}}]"}}
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  ackloop: receive ack [0: 0, 3]
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  broker ACK events: count=1, start-seq=1, end-seq=1

2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  broker ACK events: count=1, start-seq=1, end-seq=1

2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  broker ACK events: count=1, start-seq=1, end-seq=1

2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  ackloop: return ack to broker loop:3
2017-11-27T21:33:26Z DBG  ackloop:  done send ack
```

I am using (more or less) the configuration that comes out of the box, but I don't understand why I'm getting the "Failed to parse mapping..." error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating Elasticsearch to 6.x so that both Elasticsearch and Heartbeat are running on the same version.